# Expo Facebook login keeps going to blank cancel screen

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo

I am trying to perform facebook login with Expo and react native using Expos Facebook Library but when I try to log in and choose "Log In with Facebook App" it just goes to a blank screen with a navbar button saying cancel... If I say log in with email/phone number however, it works.

Here is my code...

```
_loginWithFacebook = async() => {
    const {
        type, 
        token
    } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
        "429006161020305",
        {
            permissions: ["public_profile", "email"]
        }
    );

    if (type == "success") {
        alert("Heya!")
    } else if (type == "cancel") {
        alert("Canceled login")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the screen is blank when you press the login button without entering anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you face this error on standalone app, just double check the facebook app id in app.json is right and match with appId which used in `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(appId, options)`

app.json must include:

```
...
"facebookAppId": "xxx",
"facebookDisplayName": "displayName",
"facebookScheme": "fbxxx",
...
```